# Telerik UI for ASP.NET Attempting to execute code when a tab is clicked

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I am working on an web page that uses the RadTabStrip, RadTab,RadMultiPage, and RadPageView Telerik objects.

There are four tabs. The first three tabs contain various RadText, RadDropDownList, and RadListBox objects for the user to enter information. On the first page, when the user enters an ID number, a server call populates information currently on file for that number into the various controls. That works without any issues.

My problem is when the third tab is selected, I need to call a server routine that will use information entered from the first two tabs to populate the RadDropDownList and RadListBox objects on that page. The code I have written is being executed, but when it returns, the third tab is not selected and the page view of that tab is not displayed. Instead you still see the last tab that was active. In addition if the last tab was tab one, then clicking on tab two results in tab two being displayed and the contents of tab one being displayed under it.

I am calling my routine from the OnTabClick event of the RadTabStrip:

```
<telerik:RadTabStrip RenderMode="Lightweight" runat="server" ID="RadTabStrip1"  MultiPageID="RadMultiPage1" SelectedIndex="0" Skin="Silk" AutoPostBack="true"  OnTabClick="tabViewChanged"  >
```

Is there something I need to do at the end of my code to have the page view display? I tried this:

```
RadTab tab1 = RadTabStrip1.Tabs.FindTabByText("Benefits");
tab1.Selected = true;
tab1.PageView.Selected = true;
```

but it did not appear to have any effect.

I am hoping there is just some type of render call that I am missing.

I do have the RadTabStrip1 referenced in the controls to update in the Ajax Settings.

Trimmed down HTML

```
    <telerik:RadTabStrip RenderMode="Lightweight" runat="server" ID="RadTabStrip1"  MultiPageID="RadMultiPage1" SelectedIndex="0" Skin="Silk" AutoPostBack="true" OnTabClick="loadBenefits"  >
        <Tabs>
            <telerik:RadTab Text="Tab1" Width="200px" PostBack="false"></telerik:RadTab>
            <telerik:RadTab Text="Tab2" Width="200px" PostBack="false"></telerik:RadTab>
            <telerik:RadTab Text="Benefits" Width="200px" PostBack="true" ></telerik:RadTab>
            <telerik:RadTab Text="Confirmation" Width="200px" PostBack="false"></telerik:RadTab>
        </Tabs>
    </telerik:RadTabStrip>
    <telerik:RadMultiPage runat="server" ID="RadMultiPage1"  SelectedIndex="0" CssClass="outerMultiPage">
        <telerik:RadPageView runat="server" ID="RadPageView1">
                    <telerik:RadTextBox ID="payroll_id" MaxLength="9" OnTextChanged="COBRAQE_NewPayrollID" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="true"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                    <telerik:RadDateInput ID="event_date"  runat="server" />
        </telerik:RadPageView>
        <telerik:RadPageView runat="server" ID="RadPageView2">
                        <telerik:RadTextBox ID="Dependent1Name" MaxLength="35" runat="server"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                        <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="Dependent1BirthDate" Height="25px" DatePopupButton-Width="25px" RenderMode="Lightweight" runat="server"></telerik:RadDatePicker>
                        <telerik:RadDropDownList ID="Dependent1Relation" runat="server">
                            <Items>
                                <telerik:DropDownListItem Value="" Text="" />
                                <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Spouse" Value="S" />
                                <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Child" Value="C" />
                                <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="Other" Value="O" />
                            </Items>
                        </telerik:RadDropDownList>
                        <telerik:RadDropDownList ID="Dependent1Gender" runat="server">
                            <Items>
                                <telerik:DropDownListItem Value="" Text="" />
                                <telerik:DropDownListItem Value="M" Text="Male" />
                                <telerik:DropDownListItem Value="F" Text="Female" />
                            </Items>
                        </telerik:RadDropDownList>
        </telerik:RadPageView>
        <telerik:RadPageView runat="server" ID="RadPageView3">
                <telerik:RadLabel runat="server" ID="lblHealthOption" AssociatedControlID="lbHealthOption" Text="Health Benefit" />
                    <telerik:RadLabel runat="server" ID="lblHealthCost" AssociatedControlID="ddHealthOptionCost" Text="Cost" />
                    <telerik:RadLabel runat="server" ID="lblHealthDeps" AssociatedControlID="ddHealthOptionDependents" Text="Covered" />
                <telerik:RadDropDownList runat="server" ID="ddHealthOption">
                    <Items>
                        <telerik:DropDownListItem Text="None Selected" Value="0" />
                    </Items>
                    </telerik:RadDropDownList>
                    <telerik:RadTextBox runat="server" ID="txtHealthCost" Text="default" />
                    <telerik:RadListBox runat="server" ID="lbHealthDeps">
                        <Items>
                            <telerik:RadListBoxItem Text="None" Value="" />
                        </Items>
                    </telerik:RadListBox>
        </telerik:RadPageView>
        <telerik:RadPageView runat="server" ID="RadPageView4">
            <div>This tab is currently empty</div>
        </telerik:RadPageView>
    </telerik:RadMultiPage>
```

Comment: Are you declaring the content in the MultiPage views or are they pointed to separate aspx pages?  The RadTabStrip and RadMultiPage are set up to automatically select the appropriate view when you change tabs, so sounds like something may be wrong with your set up.  Can you post your html code for these controls?

Comment: If the content has to be in separate aspx pages, then I am definitely doing something wrong. All of the content for these pages is in the same aspx file as the RadTabStrip itself. I have added a pared down copy of the HTML above.

Comment: The above code works for me when I add my own server events.  Is it possible you are getting a server error and the AJAXifying is preventing you from seeing it?  Try taking off all the AJAX settings and see what happens.

Comment: I have no problem displaying the tabs with no ajax call happening. However, if an ajax call is made, the third tab does not display its contents, even if the function called has nothing but a return statement in it.

Comment: What do your AJAX settings look like?  Maybe try moving your AJAX target to a div wrapping your controls inside the third tab.  I've had similar problems trying to target Telerik controls directly with AJAX settings.

Comment: Seano666, can you give me an example of what you mean by accessing them from a div? Do you somehow access them as children of the parent div?

Comment: I mean in your ajax "UpdatedControls", do not use the tab ID itself, but make a div or Panel wrapper inside the tab (containing all your content) and use the ID of that wrapper instead.  (I'm kind of assuming what your AJAX settings code looks like since you haven't posted it, that would probably help)